# responsive styling: Using the @media tag for moving text-box below img (margins)

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

First of all, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmitch5/XsEAN/) for the particular markup/styling in question.

Main question is why the img and text box (dark_block) do not have the same margin.  Both are set to 100% width of the container div, so I'm not sure what's up.  Mind taking a look?

Other things I'm still trying to figure out and googling (thus far) has not helped me:

- When the text box is in-line (to the left) of the photo container, how do I get it to be the same height as the photo container
- If the image's width is smaller than the photo container, how do I get it to center horizontally and vertically?
- For accessibility sake, can I just create a non-responsive version of the css before the @media tag stuff?

Sorry, I'm sort of new to web development, and any help would definitely be appreciated.  Also if anything in the code fragment seems awfully done, call me out!  I'd love to learn some best-practices in addition to solving the issue at hand.  Especially display types, having a hard time wrapping my head around 'em.

Appreciate you taking the time to look at this!

John

CODE:

```
<div id="home_top_container">
    <div id="photo_slider">
        <img src="redacted">
    </div>
    <div id="dark_block"></div>
</div>

#home_top_contianer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    #photo_slider{
        float:right;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 69%;
        min-width: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px){
    #photo_slider{
        float:none;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    #dark_block {
        float:left;
        background-color: #383838;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 28%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 799px){
    #dark_block {
        float:left;
        background-color: #383838;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model). The `width` of an element refers to its content. The padding, border and margin are then added it to it. That means your `#dark_block` is actually `100% + 2*10px` wide.

The proper solution would be to set `#dark_block` to `display: block` and remove both `float`and `width`. The default value for `width` is `auto`, which automatically makes the block as wide s possible without overflowing. Rule of thumb in web development: If you give a `display: block` element `width: 100%`, then you are doing something wrong.

Another simple solution would be to set `box-sizing: border-box;` on `#dark_block`, however [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is a relatively new property, so it won't work if you need to support older browsers.

---

Getting them to the same height, is not a trivial thing. You could use the [`display: table-*` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), and give them `height: 100%` but that requires you to put `#dark_block` first in the HTML.

[Quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/7rB3T/):

```
<div id="home_top_container">
  <div>
    <div id="dark_block"></div>
    <div id="photo_slider">
        <img src="http://caldwellfellows.ncsu.edu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Justin-sews.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#home_top_container > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

Again centering vertically is not a trivial thing in CSS. Your best bet would be to use `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle`.

---

Most certainly. Especially you should move all properties that are common to all media-variants to outside the media rules, so that you don't repeat them.

Also it's no need to repeat the media rules around each rule. Just have one media rule:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #photo_slider {
        /* ... */
    }
    #dark_block {
        /* ... */
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    #photo_slider {
        /* ... */
    }
    #dark_block {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Unfortunately, I don't think the table-cell display type will work, as I just read that columns must be of equal width.  I read about the box model, but I didn't think of it in terms of the width-100%.  Again, thanks!